# Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, localhost

I have the xamarin.forms application for which i am trying to connect localhost from PC to Iphone simulator in mac,Iam using the Ip address for connecting,

```
private string Uri = "http://192.168.0.16:62271/";//Windows Ip address:localhost port number    
private string GetDishesUrl = "api/DishDetails/GetDishDetails?id=5"; 

try{ 
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Uri);

    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(Uri + GetDishesUrl));
    var stringAsync = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseJson = stringAsync;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DishDetails>>(responseJson);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Here iam getting following Exception:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b0] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:879 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00191] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:194 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00052] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1029 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x00406] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:388 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x0049f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:392 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__48.MoveNext () [0x00080] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.1.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at MyApp.Services.DishDetailsService+<GetAsync>d__5.MoveNext () [0x00084] in G:\SourceTree\Projects\SourceCode\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\Services\DishDetailsService.cs:45 }`
```

while running web in windows it is working as expected.When trying to connect to mac giving an error.I  followed different approaches from internet but non of them got worked.

EDIT:I disabled firewall and connected mac and pc under same Wifi then the response is null and exception is also null.

Comment: Thanks replay @SushiHangover,but i dint disabled,could you   please tell how to disable that.

Comment: Thanks again for link @SushiHangover,i tried disabling NSAllowsArbitraryLoads even now iam getting the same error.

Comment: Test using Safari on the device/simulator on if you are access that address/url and retrieve your Json

Comment: I tried testing on simulator safari,it showing "Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server".

Comment: Actually the mac is also not connecting,showing "192.168.0.12 refused to connect"

Comment: Is there anything that i am missing?please help me to solve this.

Comment: After disabling firewall in pc,when gave url in safari in mac and iphone simulator they are showing blank pages and running the application in iphone its giving null response and the exception is also null.Where iam doing mistake please guide me.