# How to connect localhost of windows to iphone simulator in mac

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, localhost

I have xamarin.forms application for iOS and local database is created in sql server 2012 on windows 10,now i am trying to connect the localhost to the of windows to the iphone simulator.

i tried :
Connecting through IP address of the windows Pc.

Connected mac and windows under same wifi.

Disabled firewall.

none of them worked.

The code i am trying to connect is:

```
private string Uri = "http://192.168.0.16:62271/";//Windows Ip address:localhost port number    
private string GetDishesUrl = "api/DishDetails/GetDishDetails?id=5";
     try
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Uri);

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(Uri + GetDishesUrl));

                var stringAsync = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseJson = stringAsync;

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DishDetails>>(responseJson);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
```

when i disabled firewall and trying to connect to mac then i am getting `response`as null and also the exception also as null and in safari while giving Ip address along with GetDishesUrl  getting as `Bad Request-Invalid  Hostname`,How to acheive this local host connection?
I already placed this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173232/error-connectfailure-connection-refused) but i did not get it to be worked.

Comment: have you verified connectivity using Safari on the simulator?

Comment: Thanks for responding@Jason,yes i checked it is showing `Bad Request-Invalid Hostname`